# calling datasnap webservice from javascript into variable

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe5, datasnap

I have created a Datasnap REST server.
A `ReverseString` method gets created by default that simply reverses the string passed to the method.

When I invoke the method using the browser URL:

> http://dummydomain.com:81/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/ABC

I receive `{"result":["CBA"]}` as result.  (server runs on port 81 and the parameter passed to the method is ABC)

I have tried the following code to get the result into a variable in javascript, but without success:

```
var options={
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://dummydomain.com:81/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/SayHello",
  data: "ABC",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    $("p").after('<div id="data1">Your result is: ' + json.result + '</div>');
    }
}
$.ajax(options);
```

What am I doing wrong?  In the end I need 'CBA' in a variable.  If there are some good resources out there, please advise.  I have been googling but everybody seem to do it in their own way.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with REST Client addon in Firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/ You may be missing content type headers.

Comment: Hi Ertunç, thank you for advising the REST Client addon.  It works pretty cool.  When I use it I get the following response headers: 'code'
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 18
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 07:49:43 GMT
    Pragma: dssession=670648.436193.624911,dssessionexpires=1200000
`code` and in all 3 of the response body tabs I get {"result":["CBA"]} which is expected.  How should I format the JSON that will be sent to the webservice?

Comment: I don't know how you achieve it with Delphi but have a look at this for correct headers for returning JSON http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type